# macro to store RTD data

Tags: excel, office-2010, vba

i have written this simple code which i found on [using excel macro](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vh6SAj1Y7U).

```
Private Sub Macro3(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A3:A31").Value = Range("A2:A30").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

but after creating i cannot find the macro nor can i run it through VBA editor.
please help me out. i am using `ms office 2010`

**Edits**

what i actually want to implement.

i have a continuously changing value in A1 cell of my sheet. as soon as it changes i want it to be copied to A2 and value of A2 to A3 and so on...

Comment: @pnuts yes. i am new to macros so am not even able to rectify what is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also try by implementing the following macro

```
Sub Macro()
  Dim n As Integer
    n = 1
  Do
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
    Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Value
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  Loop Until n != 1
End Sub
```

now should be able to store data column vise at an periodic time interval.

Comment: The downside is that `Application.Wait` "suspends all Microsoft Excel activity and may prevent you from performing other operations on your computer while Wait is in effect. However, background processes such as printing and recalculation continue." (MS help text) ... also uniterruptable Loops impose a danger ... I'd prefer to read out N from a cell where I can control it ... instead a brute force `Esc`

Answer (score 1):

As the Video explains at 01:00,

- the code must be placed in Sheet1 (or the sheet you use to capture the server data), meaning that you have to doubleclick the sheet's name in the top left project explorer pane in VBA to access its code window
- you must use the name of the Sub() exactly as shown on Youtube ... `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`. You can either type the code by hand or select "Worksheet" and "Change" from the selection boxes above the code window. Delete the "Sub Selection_Change" Sub eventually being automatically created when you select "Worksheet" (including the `End Sub`)  This ensures that the macro is fired each time a (=any) cell in the worksheet changes.
- The `If Not Intersect(...)` cares that only a change of a certain cell is processed by the rest of the code
- if you set a breakpoint at the first line - `Private Sub ...` - using Debug/Toggle Breakpoint or {F9} - you will be able to step through the code using {F8} and watch

**Edit:**

after some googling ... `=RTD()` doesn't trigger Change macros (much to the disappointment of many) - so different strategies are needed.

`=RTD()` fetches data every now and then (time interval X) and puts it into a cell C different from your current [A2]. You could create a block of code which executes every X/2 and checks if C <> [A2] ... if yes move C to [A2] and copy the old values down.

Example:

Create a module "TimerFunctions" and add this code

```
Public IsTimer As Boolean

Sub TimerSet(IntervalSec As Date, TimerProcName As String)
    If IsTimer Then Application.OnTime Now() + IntervalSec, TimerProcName, , True
End Sub


Sub TimerAction()
    ' look for new value ... e.g. compare RTD cell [A1] with last stored value [A2]
    If [A2] <> [A1] Then
        ' your original code - move whole stack one down
        Range("A3:A31").Value = Range("A2:A30").Value
        ' copy new value on top of stack
        [A2] = [A1]
    End If

    ' do it again in 2 seconds
    TimerSet TimeValue("00:00:02"), "TimerAction"
End Sub
```

Sheet1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    IsTimer = True
    TimerSet TimeValue("00:00:02"), "TimerAction"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    IsTimer = False
End Sub
```

Now every 2 seconds the RTD function is checked for a new value, and if found the value is saved on the top of the stack while the rest of 30 is pushed 1 down. This works as soon and as long you are in the sheet. If you change to Sheet2 (= deactivate Sheet1) this mechanism stops until you go back to Sheet1 (= activate sheet).

If this timed thing should run all the time you must put a bit more effort in addressing your cells so that all this is working even if the acive sheet is another one.

Comment: i did the same way as in video and as you have stated the above points, but whenever i try to run it from VBA editor it asks me again to create a macro. and the created macro is no where to be seen in the macro list.

Comment: You don't "run it from VBA editor". You **change** the value of cell [A2] in the sheet to which this code is attached, and this change fires the `Sub Worksheet_Change(...)` code. If you want to follow its execution, set a breakpoint at the first line of code. BTW your code works very well here. Have you **save** d your book **as** a "macro enabled workbook" - extension **xlsm**? Otherwise your code will disapperar upon closing and reopening as xlsx!

Comment: ... and you do not see macros in the {Alt-F8} list when they are declared `Private` ... that's the reason of it ;)

Comment: its not working as it is shown in the video. is it because i am using `office 2010` and the video is of maybe `office 2007`. My code is attached with cell `A1` and it is changing continuously but its not getting stored below as in video.

Comment: the code per se is working here with my Excel 2010 ... as long as I change **the cell which is referenced in the `Intersect`** manually the list is copied. Please confirm from your side as well ... Maybe the `=RTD()` function doesn't trigger the Change event ...

Comment: There are lots of hints on the Internet that `=RTD()` **does not** fire Change triggers. So despite the fact that your move algorithm is working well, you need to consider other alternatives to refresh data into your sheet from external sources (e.g. by a timed routine)

Comment: ohhh, so the main reason is the `=RTD()` because of which i cannot execute the above macro. thank you @MikeD