# How to get the maximum value of a list of dynamic cells?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have an excel sheet with a B column with more than 100 rows that are dynamic from a RTD link.

This RTD link updates every milisecond and the values keeps increasing until at given moment it changes to zero. I don't need milisecond precision, I just need the last value before it changes to zero.

I need to store at column C all the maximum values before the cells in column B changes to zero.

I tried by VBA function and subs, some exemples below

```
Function max(ByVal currentValue As Range, ByVal cel As Range) As Double
    
    If (currentValue.value) > cel.value Then
        cel.value = currentValue.value
        max = cel.value
    Else
        max = currentValue.value
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I think you may have to look into the `Worksheet.Change` events and test if the `Target()` changes to zero. If so, use `Applicaiton.Undo` and retrieve the last, therefor the max, value. If this would be able to handle RTD-data that changes all the time, i don't know =)

Comment: The worksheet.change don't run when the RTD link are updated... because of this I'm trying to do with some function, but I don't know how to do

Comment: The best way is to override `Worksheet_Change`. But since it does not work, We can create an infinite loop, and keep on checking the value at specific intervals. We need to override  Workbook_Open() and put the infinite loop there. That should work. However, that won't be elegant at all and excel might crash.

Comment: @Roy, I tried this loop before... excel doesn't support and crashes, exactly how you supposed.

I think the best way is to create a function that stores the maximum value. I'm trying to develop this, any suggestion?

Comment: May be this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405912/macro-to-store-rtd-data

Answer (score 1):

You could put something in the Worksheet_Change event to watch Column B for any changes and save all the larger numbers to column C.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ColB As Range, cell As Range
    Set ColB = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(2))
    
    'If a value in column B was changed
    If Not ColB Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In ColB
            'If B is bigger than C, save value to C
            If cell.Value > cell.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

The Intersect method compares two ranges and returns only the cells they have in common. This is a quick way to check if a range is overlapping with our watched area and using it as the set for the loop ensures the code only runs on changes to column B.

Comment: Toddleson, the worksheet.change don't run when RTD links are updated. I tried with worksheet.calculate, but also without success... Because of this I'm trying with make a function that keep the maximum value, but I don't know how to do

Comment: Oh darn, I guess you'll have to use something else. I'm reading about the RTD function now, and it seems like you might be able to save all the RTD data into an array and then use the MAX function on the array. Unfortunately I don't have office 365 so I can't give you a tested piece of code to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I made by another way:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Me.Range("B3:B7")

For i = 3 To 7

    If Range("B" & i) > Range("C" & i) Then
        Range("C" & i) = Range("B" & i)
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```